# GoSwagger wrong color for @Failure routes

Tags: go, swagger, documentation, go-gin

I put the following description at the top of my function however the failure routes are displayed in green just as the success one in my browser:

[image].

```
// Register godoc
// @Schemes
// @Description Create a user
// @Tags register
// @Accept json
// @Produce json
// @Param RegisterInput body RegisterInput true "Params to create an account"
// @Success 200 {object} RegisterInput "Params of the created user"
// @Failure      400  {object}  req.HTTPError
// @Failure      404  {object}  req.HTTPError
// @Failure      500  {object}  req.HTTPError
// @Router /register [post]
```

From my understanding it should be in orange or red just like in Visual Studio:

[image]

(I tried multiple browser)

Is it normal or am I missing something to put the right colors?